# Marshal loading and exec-ing

Tags: python, bytecode, decompiling

I have this Python code:

```
import marshal, imp
if imp.get_magic() == '\x03\xf3\r\n':
    __code = marshal.loads('c\x00\x00\x00\x00.....\x00d\x01\x00k\x00.....\t\t\r\x01')
del marshal, imp
exec __code
```

The `if` condition checks wheter the Python version is the "right" version. Then `marshal` is used to load a string containing some code.

First question: How was that string generated? Maybe `compile()`? But how exactly?
and second question: Can I decompile that string? How?

Comment: That there is some scary python.

Comment: @JakobBowyer I know, right? That's why I'm trying to figure out what it's doing :P

Comment: @JakobBowyer why so scared. Explain plz

Answer (score 1):

As far as how its created, its something like this

```
a = marshal.dumps(compile("def test(): return 0", "<source>", "exec"))
```

As far as working out what it does? You should never unmarshal it. You don't know what nugget of horror is hidden in there and will get executed when you load it in.

You could probably use dis

```
print dis.disassemble_string(a)
```

This will give you each operation in the code.

The output of dis'ing the test function

```
>>    0 DUP_TOPX            0
      3 STOP_CODE      
>>    4 STOP_CODE      
      5 STOP_CODE      
      6 STOP_CODE      
      7 STOP_CODE      
>>    8 STOP_CODE      
      9 POP_TOP        
     10 STOP_CODE      
     11 STOP_CODE      
     12 STOP_CODE      
>>   13 BINARY_AND     
     14 STOP_CODE      
     15 STOP_CODE      
     16 STOP_CODE      
     17 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE    13
     20 STOP_CODE      
     21 STOP_CODE      
     22 LOAD_CONST          0 (0)
     25 MAKE_FUNCTION       0
     28 STORE_NAME          0 (0)
     31 LOAD_CONST          1 (1)
... etc etc
```

Its down to you to work through each operation and identify what it is doing. I can spot a few instructions I understand like `34 RETURN_VALUE` but the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) here should help identify the rest

Comment: I'm running this code every single day as it's a part of a custom app we have in the office. I have been running it for some good amount of time, so... That said, how can I actually see the code isntead of disassembled instructions?

Comment: @JackobBowyer  i need to know how to unmarshal it. Because I am sure it contains a simle python script

Answer (score 1):

Python interpreter can execute "Code Objects". A Code Object is what you get from [compiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) a piece of Python code.

```py
text_in_a_module = """\
def fn():
    print("hello world!")
fn()
"""

code_object = compile(text_in_a_module, "<string>", "exec")
print(code_object)
# <code object <module> at 0x104848650, file "<string>", line 1>
```

Now that you have this code object, you can execute it with `exec()` function:

```py
exec(code_object)
# hello world!
```

(You could directly pass the string to `exec()` and it would do two steps together)

Now, have you ever seen the `.pyc` files? They are compiled version of your source code right? They are basically code object. BUT, In order for them to be stored in a disk, the code object has to get serialized. With what? `marshal` module. This basically generates a string o bytes which are representing a serialized code object.

```py
import marshal
code_object = compile(text_in_a_module, "<string>", "exec")
print(marshal.dumps(code_object))

# b'\xe3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00[...]
```

I recommend you to create a `.pyc` file yourself and compare it with when you pass that source code to `print(marshal.dumps(compile(source_code...`, you'll see that they are indeed the same except for a few bytes from the beginning of the file.

So some people try to hide this information from you by what you have in your question.

The process of running is then simple, you deserialize the bytes to create a code object then pass it to the `exec()`.

The code object is inspectable by passing it to the `dis.dis()`. If you can read cpython's instructions, you can build the source code from the output of `dis` module. But... It takes for ever.

They were packages like [uncompyle6](https://pypi.org/project/uncompyle6/) which did this for you, but I'm not sure if it's still working.

**Note1**: The instructions vary from a cpython interpreter version to another.

**Note2**: Deserializing an untrusted bytes can harm you.

> **Warning** The marshal module is not intended to be secure against
> erroneous or maliciously constructed data. Never unmarshal data
> received from an untrusted or unauthenticated source.